# Formula confidence interval for difference in means - one sample t-test

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test, mean

I am looking for the formula of the confidence interval for the difference between means in a one sample t-test. I have only been able to locate the formula for a two sample t-test.

Let me give an example: I have the following ten scores

```
10,12,13,11.5,9,11,11.1,11.9,12.1,9.3
```

I want to know if the mean of these scores is significantly different from my population mean of 11.5.   When I conduct a one sample t-test in SPSS I get the following results:

```
t obtained = -10.776   
SIG (i.e., P) = 0.000  
95% CI of the difference = -5.3363 to -3.4837.
```

I know how SPSS calculated t and P but not how it calculated the 95% CI of the difference.  This 95% CI of the difference is not the same as the CI for the mean.  The CI for the mean I can obtain by

$$CI =\bar{x} \pm  t S/\sqrt{N}.$$

The confidence interval in this case is: 10.16,12.01. I get the same result if I calculate this in SPSS.

So my question is: what is the formula for the CI of the difference which SPSS produces? How do I get that range? I do not want the CI for the mean. Thanks.

Comment: When you have only one sample, how do you obtain two means?  Are you saying you have a *paired* sample (that is, a dataset of $(X,Y)$ values)?

Comment: @Whuber. No I mean a one sample t-test (as outlined in Healey Statistics: A Tool for Social Research). A one sample t-test is where you are comparing a sample mean to a population mean.The example they give is that you have a mean grade for a university population (4), a sample mean for 115 engineering students and you want to use your sample mean to decide if the mean grade of engineering students is different from the university mean (4). So you only have one sample. What is the formula for the CI for sample means in this case (a one sample t-test)?

Comment: @Anne This is the first example in every statistics textbook.  See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Theoretical_example), for instance.

Comment: @ Whuber. This shows how to calculate the CI for the mean not the difference in means.  They aren't the same thing or at least SPSS doesn't think so.- confused.

Comment: @Whuber. I have edited my Q to include an example so that it is clearer that I do not want to know the CI for the mean. You can see edits above. Once again thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Since the population mean is known, so just subtract it from your data points, or from your one-sample CI.  It is rare for the population mean to be known so the software probably won't do this.

Comment: @Anne the edit doesn't change anything of substance.  The CI for the difference is obtained by subtracting the reference value of 11.5 from the endpoints of the CI of the sample mean.  The main issue seems to be a question about interpreting the SPSS output.

Comment: @Okay, yes I see. The midpoint of this interval is the difference between our sample mean and test statistic. The CI is the same as our CI for the mean because we assume that the differences have the same distribution as the distribuition of the sample means. Thanks very much.

Comment: @whuber, can you add your comments as an answer?

Comment: @Anne Because @Aaron provided the first correct answer, and my comments agree with it, I would like to invite him to provide a reply if he so chooses.

Comment: @Whuber, okay but your response is clearer.

Comment: The confidence interval provided by the OP (10.16,12.01) is correct for the data provided.  The SPSS output does not match this data in any way, whether or not the population mean is subtracted.  The output is either from a different example or there was some error in what data was passed to the function.

Answer (score 1):

The confidence interval provided by the OP (10.16, 12.01) is correct for the data provided. The SPSS output does not match this data, whether or not the population mean is subtracted. (*t* value incorrect, CI incorrect, *p*-value incorrect.) The output is either from a different example or there was some error in what data was passed to the function.

In R:

```
A = c(10, 12, 13, 11.5, 9, 11, 11.1, 11.9, 12.1, 9.3)

B = A - 11.5

t.test(A, mu=11.5)

   ### One Sample t-test
   ### data:  A
   ### t = -1.0013, df = 9, p-value = 0.3428
   ### alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 11.5
   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ### 10.16374 12.01626
   ### sample estimates:
   ### mean of x 
   ###     11.09

t.test(B, mu=0)

   ### One Sample t-test
   ### data:  B
   ### t = -1.0013, df = 9, p-value = 0.3428
   ### alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
   ### 95 percent confidence interval:
   ### -1.3362575  0.5162575
   ### sample estimates:
   ### mean of x 
   ###     -0.41
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the population mean is known, so just subtract it from your data points, or from your one-sample CI. It is rare for the population mean to be known so the software probably won't do this.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @Aaron as a community wiki answer because they are, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Comment: I've added a comment to the OP above.  This might be a correct answer conceptually, but in the actual question, the SPSS output doesn't match the data provided, so this isn't an accurate answer to the question.